# mysql query match exact string or number

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have result in `MySQL` table. 
I need to get result only where is only 6 not 26 in user_id not.

```
id   users_id

 15    6,5
 16    1,5
 18    2,8
 19    1,26
 20    6,26
 21    5,10
 22    28,6
 23    21,9 
 24    29,6
```

**i am using MySQL query**

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE users_id LIKE '%6%'
```

**Result**

```
id  user_id

15  6,5
19  1,26   why is this here..
20  6,26
22  28,6
24  29,6
```

result is not correct.
i need only :

```
id  user_id

15  6,5
22  28,6
24  29,6
```

Comment: For query like '%,6' you may get perfomance problems if you have many rows in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try::

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   user_id like '6,%' or user_id like '%,6' or user_id like '%,6,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(6, users_id) > 0 AND
        FIND_IN_SET(26, users_id) = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1133d/1)

SOURCE

- [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 0):

because your query checks if the result contains a 6 at every place.

Obviously, 26 contains 6...

You could do (other ways exist)

```
where (users_id like '6,%' or users_id like '%,6')
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e49c4/2)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE users_id IN ('6');
```

should just match the 6.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 0):

Or without knowing about FIND_IN_SET or about 'OR' you just could:

```
id   users_id

 15    |6|5|
 16    |1|5|
 18    |2|6|
```

and select user_id like '%|6|%'